# Returning true or false from a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, each

I'm trying to write a simple jQuery plugin to test whether a canvas is blank or not. However, I am having trouble returning a boolean.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({ 
        isBlank : function() {
            return this.each(function () {
                var context = this.getContext('2d'),
                    imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, this.offsetWidth, this.offsetHeight);

                for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
                    if (imageData.data[i+3] !== 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

For some reason, this returns the `canvas` object, and not the boolean. When I take my code out of the `each` loop, however, it returns the boolean as expected.

How can I get this to work with the `each` loop?

Comment: You can't return a `this.each`, cause it return the own element. You need make a new variable and set it `false`, for instance, run the `this.each` without return, set this variable to a new value, that will be returned, and return the variable content.

Comment: @DavidRodrigues Could you provide an example? I'm struggling to visualise what you're saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's returning the canvas because that's what's being returned from the function `isBlank`.  `return this.each(...)` returns the jQuery object `isBlank` was called on.

You need to set a variable before the `.each`, set it to true or false when needed, and then return that instead.

Note: Inside `.each`, `return false` functions like `break` and `return true` functions like `continue`.

Example:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({ 
        isBlank : function() {
            var ret = true;
            this.each(function () {
                var context = this.getContext('2d'),
                    imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, this.offsetWidth, this.offsetHeight);

                for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
                    if (imageData.data[i+3] !== 0) {
                        ret = false;
                    }
                }
            });
            return ret;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({ 
        isBlank : function() {
            var result = true;
            this.each(function () {
                var context = this.getContext('2d'),
                    imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, this.offsetWidth, this.offsetHeight);

                for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
                    if (imageData.data[i+3] !== 0) {
                        result = false;
                    }
                }
            });
            return result;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Basically, pull out the superfluous `return` statements, and return one value at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is calling a return on `this.each`, which should return the object you're calling `.isBlank` on.  I'd remove the return on the each <strike>and see if the behavior you're expecting comes through</strike> and declare a variable outside of the `.each` call that is set by the `.each` and returned instead, like Rocket mentioned in his answer.

Comment: If he removed the `return` from before `this.each`, `isBlank` would return nothing.

Comment: Hmm, I've just given that a shot. It didn't seem to help. It works perfectly outside of the `each`, but I want it to loop through each element provided, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

By design here your plugin is able to take multiple elements. That's why you iterate over `this`.

What if you pass in multiple objects, some blank, some not? Either code the plugin to take only one object or consider changing how your plugin informs you of the status of the canvas. instead of returning false you could add a class to elements that are blank, or a data tag.

The methods in the above answers will work, but if you use them I'd suggest changing the plugin name to "AreAllBlank()"